# Facebook Requests 2.0 Error #200 All users in param ids must have accepted TOS

Tags: php, facebook

I am working on an app through my developer test account and all I am doing is trying to post a test notification to my user. I am doing this using the facebook requests 2.0 documentation, so my code looks like this:

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
              "client_id=" . $app_id .
              "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
              "&grant_type=client_credentials";

              $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);


              $user_id = $this->user->id;
              $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
                               $user_id .
                               "/apprequests?message='testing notification'" . 
                               "&"  .   
                               $app_access_token . "&method=post";

              $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
              echo "Request id number: " . $result;
```

When i do this I get an error on the page that says "failed to open stream", however when I copy and paste the url into the address bar I don't get any errors and get returned a request id.  Anybody know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using curl instead of `file_get_contents`. `file_get_contents` used to throw errors for some reason.

the cpde for the curl is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apprequest_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I know I'm a litle late, but I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You should set [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to `On`